# data consistency in R: table vs ==

Tags: r

I observe this:

```
> class(x)
[1] "numeric"
> str(x) 
num [1:2500] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
> table(x)
   1 
2500 
> table(x == 1)
FALSE  TRUE 
  299  2201 
> all.equal(x, rep(1,length(x)))
[1] TRUE
> dput(x)
c(1, ..... 1)  # all ones
```

how is this possible? I understand that [floating point numbers should not be compared using `==` in general](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9508518/850781), but shouldn't `table` be consistent with `==`?

PS. Apparently, `table` is consistent with `all.equal` and not with `==` because it converts its arguments to factors (i.e., strings) first.

PPS. `table(x-1)` shows the non-0 values.

Comment: For me it works fine

Comment: @sds Not sure what your comment means. How about a reproducible example?

Comment: What does  `all.equal(x, 1)` give you?

Comment: @Gregor: as I said, of course this is FP accuracy - but how come `table` is not consistent with `==`?

Comment: Well, let's see the `dput`, `table(c(1, 1.00000000000001))` works as expected for me.

Comment: all comments so far have been addressed by my edits. thanks a lot for comments and suggestions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Where in the documentation is it promised that they would be consistent? `table` expects "one or more objects which can be interpreted as factors", i.e., internally does `factor(x)`, which turns `x` first into a character and then into a factor.

```
x <- 1 - 1e-16
x == 1
#[1] FALSE
as.character(x)
#1] "1"
factor(x) == "1"
#[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

Just addressing a possible misunderstanding about what `all.equal` does. `table`
is *not* consistent with `all.equal`, because the latter by default includes a tolerance factor when comparing numeric values. From `?all.equal`:

> tolerance 
>   numeric ≥ 0. Differences smaller than tolerance are not reported. The default value is close to 1.5e-8.

That is, `all.equal` should really be interpreted as meaning "all *approximately* equal" (to within a given limit of numerical precision).